# Can't change ContentControls.DateDisplayFormat

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

I try to change date content control but it did not have effect,

```
 var iControl = documents.ContentControls.Add(Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlDate, range1);
 iControl.DateDisplayFormat = "MMM dd/yy";
```

Is there something else I should update to read my format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the locale first, otherwise only common formats are 'recognized'

Here it is in VBA, I'm sure you can transform it into C# yourself:

```
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlDate)
Selection.ParentContentControl.DateDisplayLocale = wdEnglishUS
Selection.ParentContentControl.DateDisplayFormat = "MMM dd/yy"
```

Your question does not mention what your own standard locale is, but I tested with wdEnglishUS and that worked, while my own is Dutch.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDateDisplayFormat()
{
    Application word = new Application();

    Assert.IsNotNull(word);

    word.Visible = true;

    Document document = word.Documents.Add();

    var iControl = document.ContentControls.Add(Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlDate, document.Content);
    iControl.DateDisplayLocale = Word.WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUS;
    iControl.DateDisplayFormat = "MMM dd/yy";
    iControl.Tag = "Test";

    return; 
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply, http://prntscr.com/csww9j , not working idk why :(

Comment: What is your LanguageId used?

Comment: I got the issue, it in selected range not local date, i select long range then append content control. and when create content control first it works fine.

Comment: default is wdEnglishUS

Comment: Indeed, to make things complete I added a TestMethod for a working scenario. Good to have it solved!